# Use wp_redirect to add a parameter

Tags: urls, wp-redirect

I am trying to add a function to my child theme to append the currently logged user as a parameter. For example, when the user test1 logs in and clicks on the following page:

```
http://www.example.com/my-wishlist
```

I want her to be redirected automatically to

```
http://www.example.com/my-wishlist/?user=test1
```

So far I did the following but it ends in a loop:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();    
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com/my-wishlist/?user='.$current_user->user_login );   
    exit;
}
```

I would appreciate some help. Thank you

Comment: Did you try javascript redirect? Just put your user name to redirect url with php tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use [add_query_arg](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) to make sure the url is created the right way. How is the wishlist link outputted? Trough wp_nav_menu? I would add it to the link on creation, so you don't have to use wp_redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the redirect loop because your script isn't checking if the user already is redirected.

Try adding another condition to your `if` to check for the user variable...

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();    
if ( is_user_logged_in() && !isset( $_GET['user'] ) ) {
    wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com/my-wishlist/?user='.$current_user->user_login );   
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I did what you suggest and seems to add the parameter as expected (with no loop). The problem now, however, is that no matter what link I click on the page it always goes to the page specified in the script (eg. I click home and it still redirects me).

Tried this but it does not work.

$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); if ( is_user_logged_in() && !isset( $_GET['user'] ) && is_page( 'my-wishlist' ) ) { wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com/my-wishlist/?user='.$current_user->user_login ); exit; }